# Painting the JPanel which created with own Painter

Tags: java, swing, awt, paint, gradient

I need learn the logic how can i change `JPanel` color which created own Painter method. I create a sample project for illustration;

Issue: Direct color changing code in button action not change anything.

Question 1) Is override the `paintComponent` method is proper way for paint he `JPanel` with `Gradient` colors while panel creation?

Question 2) How can i change the background color of this `JPanel` with other `Gradient` color or `Direct` color?

**--CODE--**

```
package tryingproject2;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class TryingProject2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        class ImagePanel extends JPanel{

            public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                int w = getWidth();
                int h = getHeight();
                Color color1;
                Color color2;
                color1 = new Color(223,130,24,255);
                color2 = new Color(255,255,255,255);

                GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, color1, w, 0, color2);
                g2d.setPaint(gp);
                g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
            }

        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel userPanel = new ImagePanel();
        userPanel.setBounds(100, 40, 200, 200);
        userPanel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel newLabel = new JLabel("Sample Label");
        newLabel.setBounds(50, 10, 100, 100);
        userPanel.add(newLabel);


        JButton button = new JButton("Change Color To Red");
        button.setBounds(100, 300, 200, 40);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
              userPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
              userPanel.repaint();
              System.out.println("Button Pressed.");
            } 
        });

        frame.add(userPanel);
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: When you override paintComponent, the first thing your method must do is call `super.paintComponent(g);`.

Comment: *"Question 1) Is override the paintComponent method is proper way for paint he JPanel with Gradient colors while panel creation?" - Yes; But see VGR comment; *"Question 2) How can i change the background color of this JPanel with other Gradient color or Direct color?"* - Use instance fields to store the current value, use setters to change them and getters to retrieve them, call `repaint` on the component to schedule it for repainting.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rearranged some of your code to get rid of other problems.

Here's the GUI I created.

[image: Color Gradient GUI 1]

Here's the GUI after I left clicked the button.

[image: Color Gradient GUI 2]

I made the following changes to your code.

1. I moved all of the JFrame code into a run method, so I could get out of static methods and into object-oriented classes and methods as fast as possible.
2. I added a call to the SwingUtilitiles invokeLater method to ensure that Swing components are created and modified on the [Event Dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
3. I created a createMainPanel method to create the main panel.  Instead of using ugly null layouts with pixel precision settings, I used a [Swing layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), the BorderLayout, to position the components.  This allows the user to expand the GUI to fill the screen, as well as the GUI fitting different computers with different screen sizes.
4. The ImagePanel class is a complete, first-class Java class.  That means you can have class fields and class constructors.  I provided a way to set the colors from outside the class.  Set both colors to the same color if you don't want a gradient.
5. The paintComponent method of the ImagePanel class should start with a super call, to maintain the Swing Paint chain.  The paintComponent method should do nothing but paint.  Period.  Full stop.  Nothing else.  I removed the code that had nothing to do with painting.
6. Looking in the actionPerformed method inside the createMainPanel method, you see how I change one of the gradient colors and perform a repaint.  The action listener is the controller of your GUI.  Only controller code should change the model (the colors in ImagePanel) or the view (ImagePanel and the JFrame).  Always look for the [model / view / controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) when creating a Swing GUI.

Here's the revised code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TryingProject2 implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TryingProject2());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Color Gradient Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel imageLabelPanel = new JPanel();
        imageLabelPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        final ImagePanel imagePanel = new ImagePanel(new Color(223, 130, 24,
                255), new Color(255, 255, 255, 255));
        imageLabelPanel.add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JLabel newLabel = new JLabel("Sample Label");
        newLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        imageLabelPanel.add(newLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        panel.add(imageLabelPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton button = new JButton("Change Color To Red");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                imagePanel.setColor1(Color.RED);
                imagePanel.repaint();
                System.out.println("Button Pressed.");
            }
        });
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        return panel;
    }

    public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6970287820048941335L;

        private Color color1;
        private Color color2;

        public ImagePanel(Color color1, Color color2) {
            this.color1 = color1;
            this.color2 = color2;
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        }

        public void setColor1(Color color1) {
            this.color1 = color1;
        }

        public void setColor2(Color color2) {
            this.color2 = color2;
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            int w = getWidth();
            int h = getHeight();

            GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, color1, w, 0, color2);
            g2d.setPaint(gp);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts first Gilbert. This one is really instructive. I learn some mechanism from your code. But i use NetBeans GUI Builder for creatng the GUI and i have many JPanel for change colors depends on some if else statements. How can i implement your solution to my whole real project i don't know yet. But carefully reading your example thanks.

Comment: I solve my issue from very different way. Hard to explaing but this solution enough for this illustration. I will accept the answer. Thank you again.